# easy_install lxml error on Redhat

Tags: python, lxml, scrapy

I have tried several ways to install lxml (actually I need to install Scrapy, which depend on lxml installed), easy_install, pip, build from source, but they didn't work out.

Now I use: STATIC_DEPS=true easy_install lxml. But got the following error:

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /tmp/easy_install-mptFTT/lxml-3.0alpha2/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(exslt.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /tmp/easy_install-mptFTT/lxml-3.0alpha2/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a:
>   could not read symbols: Bad value

Not sure what does the error mean. I use Python 2.7.3.

Comment: you dont say what version of redhat, but with rhel6, there is a python-lxml package in the repo.  Will that work for your dependency?

Comment: @tMC Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

Comment: a python-lxml package for redhat 5 is in the EPEL repo. http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Answer (score -2):

maybe you need to install libxml2-dev and libxslt-dev
in ubuntu do 
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

Comment: Good instructions for Ubuntu, but the title indicates he's running Red Hat.

Comment: I installed libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel using yum on Red Hat 6 and then built lxml without the STATIC_DEPS define. It failed to compile lxml.etree.c with numerous undefined symbols. I have a feeling that superche tried using the system libxml2 and libxslt with similar results and then tried the static approach. I'm here because I've failed similarly.